# Canonical URLs for JS and CSS, HTTP vs HTTPS

Tags: http, iis, https

I am using the IIS Search Engine Optimization Toolkit to scan over a site of mine.  One of the compaints it has is that there are multiple canonical URLs for my static assets, e.g.

- http://example.com links to http://example.com/styles.css
- https://example.com links to https://example.com/styles.css

It is of course correct, the same file is linked differently on the secure pages.  This is only happening for static resources, the actual HTML pages all have single canonical URLs.

Should I leave this as is an ignore the toolkit or is there a better arrangement.  I need to consider all angles, e.g.

- Performance (browser caching, server load)
- SEO (duplicate content penalties)
- Usability (mixed content warnings)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide if it's better for you to receive this message from your analysis toolkit, or for your customers to be told that not all items on the page are secure.

I know what my choice would be...

Comment: An alternative would be to always link to secure versions of the static files of course.

Comment: I was kind of hoping there was a way to fix the toolkit.

Comment: I'm not really sure that you're going to be able to.